# LWC: Navigating to Registration or Forgot Password pages in Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I have a LWC component with a link that I want to navigate directly to the Registration page in the Community. I’m using the following code to link to it.

```js
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            name: 'Register'
        }
    });
```

When I click the link it sends me to an Invalid Page. The same is true if I try to link to the `Forgot_Password` page. If I replace the `name` value with another standard page's api name, it works fine. Is there something unique about these pages that prevents them from being linked to directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to call a custom page? If not, I'm not sure if "Register" is a supported name parameter. Please check the below link:

[PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)

How about trying to redirect to a url, which you can buildup for you community?

```
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
      type: "standard__webPage",
      attributes: {
        url: "/communityURL/"
     },
   }).then((generatedUrl) => {
   window.open(generatedUrl);
});
```

Comment: it's the standard Salesforce registration page in Community builder. "Register" is the Api Name of the page.

Comment: Your solution does work. I used a non-absolute path of `login/ForgotPassword`. I would like to know why you can't target it like you can a standard page with the api name.

Comment: @SteveSchrab I'm not really sure, but the documentation is saying that supported pages are: 
Supported pages are:
Home
Account Management
Contact Support
Error
Login
My Account
Top Articles
Topic Catalog
Custom pages

But I'm not able to tell you exactly why Salesforce is doing so. 
Glad that my solution is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work now, just tested it in my community

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        name: 'Register'
    }
});
```